# Weird explorer behaviour on lan access

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, windows-explorer

i have a computer that when i access it's shared folder, after a while (it changes) stops to responds and hangs explorer.exe on my machine. I first thinked about a faulty lan adapter, but then i checked that every other software (apache, filezilla, emule, utorrent) is perfectly working, so it can't be an hardware fault. 
It could happens after few seconds, sometimes after few minutes... maybe i just open a shared folder and then leave the window opened.. after a while exploer.exe on my computer hangs. Of course, if i open a shared folder and then start to copy a file, if the copy end before the hang, everything it's ok (the file is copied perfectly) but if an hangs happen, the copy stops. I've done tests with other computer, and every explorer.exe hangs after a while. On the weird computer i have windows xp sp3.
Until the last week it was perfectly working. I've done a full antivirus check, nothing was found. I don't know how to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i've done an experiment. I have set an ftp server, and transferred files from the server to another computer. The conncetion works and the transfer started fast, but about after 450MB of data, i've lost the connection. I connected again, but i had the same problems where everything was totally slow and i was not able to use it from lan again until reeboted.
I'm accessing the server by ip address, not using shortcut or even surfing it from network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Does the folder in question contain media files of some description?

This can happen with folders containing media files because Explorer or search indexer 'touches' the contents of a share, which in turn can cause the codec for each media item to be loaded. If one of those codec/file combinations is duff, you can end up with crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer have a shortcut to the shared folder on your Windows desktop? If so, try deleting the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I've done another experiment: i've used ubuntu to temporary boot with another o.s. and with it i've been able to tranfer 15gb of data flawlessy.